# How can I install a dual boot configuration with Ubuntu and Windows XP?

Tags: dual-boot

First I want to install Ubuntu completely, and then I want to install Windows XP 64 bit as the 2nd boot OS.  How can I do this?  Currently I am using Windows XP as the main OS and 2nd boot is Ubuntu.

Comment: Do you have an existing Windows and Ubuntu installation? Do you just want to change the boot order?

Comment: I didn't know which so I sent you articles two both ways. As well as what I thought was the best setup to dual boot windows and Ubuntu. :)

Answer (score 2):

I would recommend formating your computer to fresh windows XP 64 install. Then I would create two partitions. Install Ubuntu on to the partition that is not installed by windows.

I feel that this is the best setup for maintaining to two systems on a dual boot machine have done it for years.

Here is a tutorial on this process. Windows install [first](http://apcmag.com/how_to_dual_boot_windows_xp_and_linux_xp_installed_first.htm) Linux installed [first](http://apcmag.com/how_to_dual_boot_linux_and_windows_xp_linux_installed_first.htm)

Answer (score 1):

If you want to keep your XP follow this I posted to someone earlier:

Resize your Windows XP partition by going to Start > My Computer > Right Click and select Management > Disk Management > Right click your Windows Partition and Select Shrink Volume. Just shrink to whatever Windows suggests and leave it Unallocated.

On the Ubuntu install you select your Unallocated partition and click "New" and select the file system as a "EXT3" and select the mount point as "/" and click Okay (If you dont want swap)

If you do want swap type in the amount you want (in MB) select the file system as a "Swap Partition" and there is no mount point. Click Okay then you do the step in the paragraph above

After Install, Windows will now be in your GRUB menu with Ubuntu as default but that can be fixed by editing your /boot/menu.lst

**NOTE: IT WAS FOR WIN 7 BUT I MADE THE NECESSARY CHANGES**

Answer (score 1):

Do you just want Ubuntu to appear as the first option in the boot menu?

If so:

1. Boot into Ubuntu
2. Install StartUp-Manager (you can search 'StartUp-Manager' in Ubuntu Software Centre)
3. Run System -> Administration -> StartUp-Manager
4. Change the default operating system to Ubuntu (choose the one with the highest Linux kernel version)
5. Reboot, Ubuntu should appear as the first option.

NOTE: I am assuming you did a normal dual boot not a wubi install.